# Get cryptsetup working without typing a password

Tags: password, encryption

I have used cryptsetup to encrypt an external hard drive.

I have no problem at using the encrypted hard drive in this way:

```
/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 backup   
// typing password   
// mounting the partition   
// doing something   
// unmounting the partition  
/sbin/cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/backup
```

But my next requirement was to be able to do it without the need of typing a password.

Then I created a binary file with the hash of my password via this command:

```
hashalot -n 32 ripemd160 > volume_key
```

and then:

```
/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen -d volume_key /dev/sdc1 backup
```

but I get this error:

```
Command failed: No key available with this passphrase.
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: but you never accept answers since your own edit?

Answer (score 3):

In case you land here like I did looking for the answer, it goes like this:

Then I created a binary file with the hash of my password via this command:

```
 hashalot -n 32 ripemd160 > volume_key
```

and then you must:

```
 /sbin/cryptsetup luksAddKey <device> volume_key       
 Enter any passphrase:   <- enter current passphrase aka: "typing password"
```

Now cryptsetup has added your file (volume_key) as another key to your volume. Technically, you can use any file you want for this key. A jpg image, or even any file full of random text.

Finally, now you can do this:

```
 /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen -d volume_key /dev/sdc1 backup
```

cryptsetup will use the key file if it is there, or ask for your passphrase if it cannot find the file.

Comment: Since luksAddKey creates the hashed volume-key, but complains if there is no file use: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/volume-key bs=512 count=8 && /sbin/cryptsetup luksAddKey /root/container-key <device>` then `echo '/media/user/progs <device> /root/container-key luks,nofail' >> /etc/crypttab` (can use UUID)

Answer (score 1):

cryptsetup man page suggests the following about the -d parameter: *"If you want to set a new key via a key file, you have to use a positional arg to luksFormat or luksAddKey."*

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the volume_key file will be hashed by cryptsetup, so you don't need to do that yourself?

Comment: I think this is right; try using your incantation again, but put the passphrase itself in volume_key.